# ¿Cómo validar usuario y contraseña para enviar a otra pagina con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, validación

Tengo un script que funciona casi totalmente bien y si se cumple una condición, debe redireccionar a una página, sin embargo, no hace nada. Debería de mandarme a la página "procesoChecador.php" pero no hace nada. Gracias de antemano.

```js
<div id="pie">
     <script type="text/javascript">
   function Validar(user,pwd)
    {
     user=document.getElementById(user);
     pwd=document.getElementById(pwd);
     if(user.value=="")
   {
    alert("El campo Nombre esta vacio");
    user.focus();
    return false;
   }
     else
   {
    if(pwd.value=="")
     {
      alert("El campo Passwd esta vacio");
      pwd.focus();
      return false;
     }
    else
     {
      var usuario = document.formulario.user.value;
      var password = document.formulario.password.value;
      window.location='procesoChecador.php?usuario='+usuario+'&pw='+password;
      return true;
     }
   }
    }
  </script>
     <form name="formulario" onSubmit="return Validar('usuario','pw')">
            <input type='text' name='user' id='usuario' placeholder='Usuario' style='background-color:#FF9;' /><br />
            <input type='password' name='password' id='pw' placeholder='Contraseña' style='margin-top:10px; background-color:#FF9' /><br />
            <input id='boton' type="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: ¿A qué te referís con 'funciona casi totalmente'? ¿qué es lo que no funciona?
¿Podrías dar más detalle del error?

Answer (score -1):

Hola puedes intentar cambiando la linea

```
window.location
```

por la siguiente

```
window.location.href
```

esto te debe redireccionar sin problema. Si la página se encuentra embebida le agregas el `top` quedando de la siguiente manera

```
window.top.location.href
```